# When is the right time to subclass?

Tags: php, oop

Working on a database class that got quite big, and is likely to get much bigger, I started writing a lot of attributes and methods related to one specific aspect of the database (users, comments, pages etc.) So it feels like it's about time to subclass the database class to several classes, each dealing with their own aspect, and only have the database class contain the absolute core functionality.

However, doing that feels like making extra classes and dealing with `includes` and the likes for nothing. The code is pretty maintainable as-is and "divided" (via comments) into the correct sections, and it's not like a "big" class is gonna damage performance noticeable.

So, I come to you: When is the right time, in your opinion and experience, to subclass? Not just in this specific case, but in general terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go by logical grouping of methods and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal. I have like 50 models which deal with all kind of data (a lot of tables).

Problem with includes can be easily solved by following a naming convention and using autoloaders.

For example, I call all my classes like this - ClassNameModel.php and put them in a specific directory.

The autoloader would look like this:

```
function customAutoloader($class_name){
    $file_name = $class_name . ".php";

    //Modelis
    if(substr($class_name, -5) === "Model"){
        if(is_readable("/models/" . $file_name)){
            require_once("/models/" . $file_name);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

and in the main index or config or whatever:

```
spl_autoload_register('customAutoloader');
```

and no more includes...

Comment: The model should not depend on your database structure. Model itself shouldn't even be aware that there exists a database.

Comment: teresko, aren't you confusing model with a controller? Anyways, I use an ORM (RedBean) layer...

Comment: model deals with business logic. Which does not change is the storage medium is switched. You should not rewrite Model, if you move from an SQL storage to NoSQL or start to use external REST API. Besides, if you use ORM for Model, then it is impossible to write unit-tests for it ( you cannot test it in isolation ).

Comment: No, I mean I use the ORM withing the model, e.g. `function getUser($id){ return ORM::load("users", $id); }` But still I don't get you. Am I missing a letter from the "MVC"? If I switch to a REST API, what then should I rewrite if not the model?

Comment: You should have to rewrite only the [Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) which is responsible for storage and retrieval of domain objects. And in your example, your code is tightly coupled with class named "ORM", which makes it untestable. Anyway, **the point** : you are not so much missing a letter, but in a well written model, the domain business logic is not coupled with database access.